# How to allow user to enter their own remote repo using Gulp task

Tags: javascript, git, gulp

I'm trying to allow the user to enter their own remote repository URL using a Gulp-git task called 'gulp remote'

Below is the code...

```
gulp.task('remote', function(){
    gulp.src('package.json')
    .pipe(prompt.prompt({
        type: 'input',
        name: 'remote',
        message: 'Please enter remote message...'
    },  function(res){
      return gulp.src([ '!node_modules/', './*' ], {buffer:false})
      .pipe(git.addRemote(res.remote));
    }));
});
```

The code prompts the user to enter their own URL into the terminal but returns an error when the URL is placed into the terminal and entered.

Comment: What are you trying to do? That task doesn't make sense, and most definitely does not do whatever it is you're intending.

Comment: I'm trying to allow the user to paste or type in the URL to the repository the want to copy from github. @deefour Ideally they would just need to run the gulp command and then be prompted to enter the URL, hit enter and the repo would be copied